# Problem about fitting classification trees in R

Tags: r, regression, classification, decision-tree

I'm using the data set Carseats to fit into a classification tree. What I did here is trying to make a new variable "High" to indicate if the Sales is high or low, then use all other variables to predict variable "High".

```
attach(Carseats)
High <- ifelse(Sales <= 8, "No", "Yes")
Carseats <- data.frame(Carseats, High)
tree.carseats <- tree(High~.-Sales, Carseats)
summary(tree.carseats)
```

But I have two problems:

1. When I ran the tree() function above, I got the object "tree.carseats" readily as well as a warning messsage "In tree(High ~ . - Sales, Carseats) : NAs introduced by coercion". I have used any(is.na()) to check all variables in this model and found no NA. So what is the problem with this warning message?
2. When I ran summary() function, I failed and got the error information:
   "Error in y - frame$yval[object$where] :
   non-numeric argument to binary operator"
   What's the reason of this error?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, **do not `attach`**, it's the most useless instruction in R and it is potentially dangerous.

As for the warning, it can be solved by coercing `High` to factor.

```
library(tree)

data(Carseats, package = "ISLR")    
str(Carseats)

Carseats$High <- factor(ifelse(Carseats$Sales <= 8, "No", "Yes"))
tree.carseats <- tree(High ~ . -Sales, Carseats)
summary(tree.carseats)
#
#Classification tree:
#tree(formula = High ~ . - Sales, data = Carseats)
#Variables actually used in tree construction:
#[1] "ShelveLoc"   "Price"       "Income"      "CompPrice"   "Population" 
#[6] "Advertising" "Age"         "US"         
#Number of terminal nodes:  27 
#Residual mean deviance:  0.4575 = 170.7 / 373 
#Misclassification error rate: 0.09 = 36 / 400
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser but it doesn't wok for me...

Comment: @kaiyuwei "doesn't work" is not very clear, what is the problem, exactly?

Comment: Same error messages as before.   "In tree(High ~ . - Sales, Carseats) : NAs introduced by coercion"  and  "Error in y - frame$yval[object$where] : non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Comment: @kaiyuwei Are you using the data set `Carseats` found in package `ISLR`? If yes, have you tried closing and restarting R? The code in my answer doesn't throw errors or warnings with me, I cannot reproduce the error. The warning about `NA`'s only occurs if `High` is not a factor.

Comment: @kaiyuwei I have added the output of `summary`.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway. I think maybe it was because of my system.

Comment: @kaiyuwei What does `packageVersion('tree')` return? Mine is `‘1.0.40’`, R 4.0.3, Ubuntu 20.10.1 LTS.

Comment: Thank your for trying to solve my problem. Mine is same as yours. And I tried to unistall and reinstall the Rstudio but it still doesn't work for me.